# Assigning url of image to tag <img> html

Tags: javascript, html, json

hello I have this in file index:

```
<img id="lang__Logo" class="lang__L" atl="Logo Lang">
```

and I want to assign an image from a file languages.json and I havethis:

```
"en": {
    "langdesc": "English",
    "main__l--ch1": "About Me",
    "main__l--ch2": "Estudies",
    "main__l--ch3": "Skills",
    "main__l--ch4": "Biefcase",
    "main__l--ch5": "Contact",
    "lang__Logo": "../imagenes/united-kingdom.png"
```

so I'm assigning url's image in this line "lang__Logo": "../imagenes/united-kingdom.png"

but it is not working, the image not show in the file index, why? what I'm doing wrong

this I want:
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried please?

Comment: Hi!!! I'm creating a website multi languages(english/spanish) so, I'm assigning the content from languages.json, and i'm using javascript to select languages..... so went users select "English" I want to show a picture's flag of "united-kingdom" but if users select "Spanish language" I want to show a picture's flag   of "spain"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this example can help

```
lang.js

lang = {
    "eng":{
        "lang_logo" : "img1.png",
        "text" : "English"
    },
    "esp":{
        "lang_logo" : "img2.png",
        "text" : "Spanish"
    }
}

const selectLang = document.querySelector("#selectLang")
const langImg = document.querySelector("#langImg")
const langTxt = document.querySelector("#langTxt")

selectLang.addEventListener("change", function(){
    langImg.src = lang[this.value].lang_logo
    langTxt.innerText = lang[this.value].text
})
```

this is the html

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="" id="selectLang">
        <option value="eng">english</option>
        <option value="esp">spanish</option>
    </select>
    <img id="langImg" src="img1.png" alt="">
    <p id="langTxt">English</p>

    <script src="lang.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

if it's not showing try to check if the img paths are correct